# Timespan Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm doing a website in Asp.Net(Framework 4.0), using SQL server 2008 r2.

My Database fieldname "RegisterTime" & datatype for is time(7).

While inserting into database i'hv used `TimeSpan time= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;` It insert successfully.

[image]

When I'm trying to retrieve my id using time as an input method, it gives error input string was not in correct format.

Code as follows.

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderId  FROM tbl_Orders WHERE UserId ='" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString()) + "' And RegisterTime='" + time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss.ff") + "'", con);
 con.Open();
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (dr.HasRows)
 {
    orderid = ""; 
    orderid = dr["OrderId"].ToString();
 }
```

While adding   `CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` 
Gives error

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this!

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderId  FROM tbl_Orders WHERE UserId ='" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString()) + "' And RegisterTime='" + time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff") + "'", con);
```

In your code, there is a typo,

```
time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss.ff") to time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.ff")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should try it like this

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
"' And RegisterTime='" + time.ToString("hh:mm:ss.ff",ci) + "'", con);
```

for .Net 4.0 There is a [configuration switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee803802.aspx) to restore the old behaviour of TimeSpan.

In .NET 3.5 and earlier, the `TimeSpan` struct wasn't `IFormattable`. When `string.Format` and related methods see something like `{0:something}` and the argument supplied isn't `IFormattable`, they have nowhere to put that format string, and they just discard it.

Comment: your code give error "Format Exception was unhandled by user code". Input string was not in correct format.

Comment: plz look at the link [TimeSpan_LegacyFormatMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee803802.aspx) to fix the issue

Comment: I had closer look at  link provided by you.And  I'hv made changes according to link , but it still gives error.